# powershell command for creating new Inbound NAT Pool of Existing Load Balancer

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-load-balancer

I want to attach an existing Azure Load Balancer to Virtual Machine Scale Set, for this i need to create inbound nat pool so that i can take the resource ID of the inbound nat pool and pass it to the ARM Template of VMSS.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean “inbound nat pool”?

Comment: You can use Azure CLI command ```az network lb inbound-nat-pool create``` to create it. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/lb/inbound-nat-pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-lb-inbound-nat-pool-create

Comment: @NiteshSingh, since your issue has been resolved, could you please accept your or my answer? It may help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we can use the PowerShell command `New-AzLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig` to create an inbound nat pool. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/New-AzLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig?view=azps-2.8.0.

For example:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$slb = Get-AzLoadBalancer -Name "testload" -ResourceGroupName "testfun07"
$feIpConfig = Get-AzLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name "LoadBalancerFrontEnd" -Loadbalancer $slb

New-AzLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -Name "myInboundNatPool" -FrontendIpConfigurationId $feIpConfig.Id -Protocol TCP -FrontendPortRangeStart 1001 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 2000 -BackendPort 1001
```

[image]

---

## Update

If we want to use PowerShell to create Inbound NAT Pool for an existing Load balancer, we need to do the following steps

1. Create a Inbound NAT Pool

```
$slb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "testload" -ResourceGroupName "testfun07"

$feIpConfig = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name "LoadBalancerFrontEnd" -Loadbalancer $slb

Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $slb -Name "myInboundNatPool" -FrontendIpConfigurationId $feIpConfig.Id -Protocol TCP -FrontendPortRangeStart 1001 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 2000 -BackendPort 1001
```

2. Configure the ppol for the laad balancer

```
Set-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $slb -Name "myInboundNatPool" -FrontendIpConfigurationId $feIpConfig.Id -Protocol TCP -FrontendPortRangeStart 1001 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 2000 -BackendPort 1001
```

3. Update the load balancer

```
Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer -LoadBalancer $slb
```

For example

```
$name = "you account"
$password = "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $mycreds 

$slb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "testload" -ResourceGroupName "testfun07"

$feIpConfig = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name "LoadBalancerFrontEnd" -Loadbalancer $slb

Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $slb -Name "myInboundNatPool" -FrontendIpConfigurationId $feIpConfig.Id -Protocol TCP -FrontendPortRangeStart 1001 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 2000 -BackendPort 1001
 "1" | Out-File -FilePath E:\mytest.txt -Append -Encoding utf8

Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "testload" -ResourceGroupName "testfun07" | Select-Object InboundNatPools | fl | Out-File -FilePath E:\mytest.txt -Append -Encoding utf8



Set-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $slb -Name "myInboundNatPool" -FrontendIpConfigurationId $feIpConfig.Id -Protocol TCP -FrontendPortRangeStart 1001 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 2000 -BackendPort 1001

 "2" | Out-File -FilePath E:\mytest.txt -Append -Encoding utf8

Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "testload" -ResourceGroupName "testfun07" | Select-Object InboundNatPools | fl | Out-File -FilePath E:\mytest.txt -Append -Encoding utf8



Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer -LoadBalancer $slb

"3" | Out-File -FilePath E:\mytest.txt -Append -Encoding utf8

Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "testload" -ResourceGroupName "testfun07" | Select-Object InboundNatPools | fl | Out-File -FilePath E:\mytest.txt -Append -Encoding utf8
```

[image]

Comment: ya i tried that also, but i am not able get ID of the inbound nat pool with this command  `(Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName VMSS-RG -Name nbslb).InboundNatPools[0].Id` . can you please check whether you are getting the id or not.

Comment: @NiteshSingh Is that you want to create an inbound nat pool for existing load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply but finally after lot of hit and trail i found the answer.

```
New-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -Name "natpool3" -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPortRangeStart 50000 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 50119 -BackendPort 3389
$lb= Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName VMSS-RG -Name nbslb
$feip=(Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName VMSS-RG -Name nbslb).FrontendIpConfigurations[0].Id
Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -LoadBalancer $lb -FrontendIpConfigurationId $feip -Name "natpool3" -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPortRangeStart 50000 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 50119 -BackendPort 3389 
Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer -LoadBalancer $lb
```